# Blender 3D design

Tags: 3d, blender

I want to design a 3d living room using Blender. Can any one help me to find good tutorials. I saw a video tutorial in you tube but it is not enough. Videos or any other form of tutorials are OK.

Thanx.

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign.SE!  I am closing your question since this site is [mainly geared towards 2D design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq) and there are many tutorials that can be found via search engines.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource is Tufts' Blender course and its [videos](http://ocw.tufts.edu/Content/57/supplementarymaterial/678906). However if you want to design a living room, you could do it quickly with [Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/).